# iOS: Uses for the TabBar

Tags: ios

Seems I'm splitting my time equally between building my first app and posting questions on here the last few days!!

This is my first app, and the first app our designer has done.  I'm trying to meet the look and feel of what he has done but I don't think he's done the appropriate thing.  In the design there is what looks like it should be a tabbar at the bottom of some pages, but the buttons are to make a phone call and send an email.  I'm not sure that is an appropriate use of the tabbar - a toolbar would work but the icons would be too small for the design.  Is there an alternative?  Can I build what looks like a tabbar at the bottom of the screen and have it work properly?  The app at the moment is based on a navigationcontroller, so I'd have to take it apart again to use a tabbar, wouldn't I?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  As I said this is my first app and the size and complexity means I'm kind of in at the deep end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a custom view instead of a tab bar. Tab bar buttons don't have the same feel as normal buttons because they don't push down, just snap to a new highlighted state. You definitely don't have to take your app apart - you can just add in a tab bar, a custom view, or whatever in the view that needs it. I think your intuition is right that this is not a good use for a standard `UITabBar`.

Comment: How can I make it appear at the bottom of the screen properly?  It's in a navigationcontroller so has a nav bar at the top, and some pages that it will appear on have a table in the middle.  When I've tried building it with a view it seems to disappear off the bottom.

Comment: Ah, that's probably because the height of your views is still 480 points even though your navigation bar is taking up 44 (and pushing your views down.) Try resizing your views.